# Based on the function graph, in how many points the derivative equals 2?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I need to answer the question in the title for this function graph.

[[image]]

I see that the derivative is positive in $3$ segments of the graph,  and thinking about it as roughly $\frac{\bigtriangleup y}  {\bigtriangleup x}$ it should be have points where derivative is $2$ or more in the first $2$ segments where the function grows.

But I don't know where to go from here and how to find the exact number of points.

Comment: It looks like the derivative is greater than 2 at an infinite number of points.

Comment: @Jed maybe but the question is about points where it equals 2. Also, the answer is supposed to be an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint $1:$** 
The tangent at any point on the graph gives the derivative at that point.

**Hint $2:$** 
The derivative is zero at exactly $5$ points in the given range.

**Hint $3:$**
Since the function is continuous, by Intermediate Value Theorem, there must be some $c$ between $a$ and $b$, such that $f(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Can you take it from here?
(Answer is $2$)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The definition of the derivate is

> A formula for the coefficient of the tangent.